# Asymptotic time complexity of c*n*(1 - n)

Tags: time-complexity, recurrence

Suppose on solving a recurrence, I find that:

```
T(n) = c*n*(1-n) = c*n - c*n^2
```

where c is a positive constant and n the size of the input

Should I consider the asymptotic time complexity of this recurrence, O(n) as the n^2 term is negative?

UPDATE:

For example, suppose we have the following recurrence:

```
    T(n) = T(a*n) + O(n), where the factor a less than 1:
    => T(n) = c*n*(1 + a + a^2 + a^3 + ... for logan terms)
    => T(n) = c*n*(1 - a^logan)/(1 - a)
    => T(n) = c*n*(1 - n)/(1 - a) ~ c*n*(1-n)
```

Comment: No, there is something wrong with your formula. Even at n=2 your time is negative

Comment: I've updated with an example

Comment: Hint: you made an incorrect leap in reasoning, which led to a sign error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error as suggested by @meowgoesthedog in the comments is due to an incorrect leap in reasoning (there are log<sub>(1/a)</sub>n terms and not log<sub>a</sub>n); the correct derivation is as follows:

```
    T(n) = T(a*n) + O(n), where the factor a less than 1:
    => T(n) = c*n*(1 + a + a^2 + a^3 + ... for log(1/a)n terms)
    => T(n) = c*n*(1 - a^log(1/a)n)/(1 - a)
    => T(n) = c*n*(1 - n)/(1 - a) ~ c*n*(1-1/n) ~ O(n)
```